# where recordstore file is stored in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I make an application by using record store.Can i see where recordstore file is stored in blackberry? In android we can see the such storage file under File Explorer. Is it possible in blackberry to see that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage locations for record store is Application storage and this storage location is internal to the BlackBerry device. It contains the operating system, the BlackBerry Java Virtual Machine, and an internal file system. Application storage is also called flash memory and on-board memory. Application storage is the only place on a BlackBerry device from which applications can be run. All BlackBerry devices have application storage.

check out this links

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29299/Data_storage_overview_1554355_11.jsp
 http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storage_locations_1554358_11.jsp

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what record store means but if you go to Media, open the menu and select explore you will be able to explore the "file system" of the phone.